# Attached pictures not shown at recipient

Tags: mail.app, email, attachments

I send a lot of mails to many different contacts. Sometimes with attached pictures like png and jpg files.

Quite often I get people responding to me that they cannot see the attached file. And their response will almost always include the attached file, proving that they *did* get it. Often it is a Microsoft client, but I don't know for all different cases.

Sometimes I can explain that they need to check the list of attached files, if the pictures do not show inline in the text area. But other times they insist that they cannot see any traces of the attached picture, whatsoever.

This did not seem to be the case when I tested AirMail, for example.

No issues with attaching for example PDF files. I remember something about a configuration setting for attaching inline vs. not inline. But I cannot seem to find it anymore?

What can I do about this. Is it possible to make Mail.app attach files in a manner, that "all" mail clients are able to understand?

Comment: Are you dragging the photos into the mail, or attaching them with the paperclip button and Choose File dialog?

Have you seen the guidance here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/mlhl3a3acb4e/15.0/mac/12.0 ?

Comment: @rbrtl I already have the windows-friendly options turned on, etc. Still many people insist that I did not attach any pictures. Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, mail clients (and servers) can be configured in so many ways you can't foresee. Assuring that 'all mail clients' open the images without any problems is well-nigh impossible.

File size restrictions or restrictions on .jpeg files for [virus content](https://www.bullguard.com/blog/2018/01/jpeg-files-and-malware) on the server side, and email app or web-based email reader misconfiguration can lead to images not showing.

If your recipients need the images for further processing, (rather than just viewing onscreen,) I suggest packaging the images in a .zip file so the graphic file format is immaterial until the archive is unpacked. If the images can't be viewed after unpacking, the onus is on the recipient to make sure the file format can be opened.

If the images are merely for viewing or simple printing, perhaps PDFs are a solution as they are pretty universally openable.

There are too many unknowns here for a more concrete answer. Bypassing mail client peculiarities from the start may be your only recourse.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I already knew/suspected. The issue is, that I never saw this as frequent as with Apple Mail to a Microsoft client. I used many other mail clients before, but never had trouble with this. That would lead me to blieve that Apple Mail is being incompatible (or some gray area). I guess the workaround is to use another mail application, then.

Answer (score 1):

If those images are taken with an Apple device, since iOS11 those devices have defaulted to HEIC format for photos. However, this format (and codec) are not visible on Windows by default to date. Depending on how you attach those images in macOS, you may be sending the HEIC version instead of JPG.  Since macOS doesn't need to use .jpg or .heif to identify formats, it is quite easy to send images not realizing they are HEIC.

To avoid sending HEIC, (especially if you are having issues), you can change iOS camera to capture in JPG instead, using the 'more compatible' setting in Camera settings.

Comment: Typically it is jpg and png pictures. So that is not the cause. It seems to be some kind of incompatabillity in the MIME encoding of the attachments. But I cannot seem to find any details about this anywhere. Sigh :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, check there are no illegal characters in the file name, e.g. / ? < > \ : * | ” ^ are OK for Mac but not Windows PC.

To change the attachment from inline to "not inline", right click on it after attaching, then select "View as icon". I think this is on your Mac; what shows on the recipient's end will depend on their machine - but give it a try.

Another option is to zip and attach.

Comment: Thanks. There are no special characters involved. This is for many, many pictures. It is a general thing. How it is shown on my computer does not affect this situation for the recipient. I suppose it is a compatibility issue, like something wrong with the specific MIME encoding. That's what I'm looking for an explanation on.